# The difference between IO and UIO in scalaz ZIO

Tags: scala, scalaz, zio

What is the difference between IO and UIO in the new version from ZIO for example `UIO[Long]` and `IO[Nothing, Long]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference. Type `UIO[+A] = ZIO[Any, Nothing, A]` and type `IO[+E, +A] = ZIO[Any, E, A]`. So both `UIO[Long]` and `IO[Nothing, Long]` are `ZIO[Any, Nothing, Long]` (i.e. any environment, no errors and value of `Long`).

You could check this by verifying that

```
implicitly[UIO[Long] =:= IO[Nothing, Long]]
implicitly[IO[Nothing, Long] =:= UIO[Long]]
```

compile.

`UIO[A]` is `IO[Nothing, A]`.